# my custom function not working

Tags: php, function

i create function called `empty_fields` but i can't figure out, to make it work..

```
<?php
function empty_fields($field_name)
{
    if(!empty($order[$field_name]))
    {
        $output = "<li>Indigofera - " . $order[$field_name] . "Kg</li>";
    } else { $output = null; }

    return $output;
}
```

to display in html

```
<?php empty_fields('indigofera'); ?>
```

Comment: Your output is returned by function. To see it in html you should `echo`

Comment: @u_mulder yes I try 'echo' `<?php echo empty_fields('indigofera'); ?>` but still not working.

Comment: Maybe it's `not working` because `$output` is `null`?

Comment: where does `$order` come from?

Comment: And it's obviously `null` because `$order` not exists in scope of your function

Comment: $order comes from my query `while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>`

Comment: and where is this query? are you using classes and functions? or is this in the global scope?

Comment: thank you everyone for sharing your idea I guess i figure out the problem, i need to set $order as a global variable.  `global $order;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$order` as a global variable, use:

```
function empty_fields($field_name)
{
    global $order;

    $output = null;
    if(!empty($order[$field_name]))
    {
        $output = "<li>Indigofera - " . $order[$field_name] . "Kg</li>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

and use it:

```
<?php echo empty_fields('indigofera'); ?>
```

EDIT: the OOP way:

```
class Orders
{
     private $order = null;

     public function get_order()
     {
         $this->order = //....
     }

     public function empty_fields($field_name)
     {
         if(!isset($this->order) || empty($order[$field_name])) return;

         return "<li>Indigofera - " . $order[$field_name] . "Kg</li>";
     }
}
```

and use it:

```
<?php

$orders = new Orders();
$orders->get_order();
echo $orders->empty_fields("indigofera");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(!empty($order['$field_name'])){
```

to

```
if(!empty($order[$field_name])){
```

'$field_name' does not evaluate to anything and it will search for

key `'$field_name'` in the `$orders` array everytime, hence will not work.

Hope it works.

Comment: There is also the one in `$output = "<li>Indigofera - " . $order['$field_name'] . "Kg</li>";` :)

Comment: and if he want output html to browser also need to add

    `<?php echo empty_fields('indigofera'); ?>`